# Docker swarm inconsistency

Tags: docker, networkx, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

my swam is inconsistent each time I create something like Networks, Secrets it says that some of us are already exist when it is  not the case, I was in swarm that I left for this reason and loose all my secrets and now I am I a new one and I have the same issue

1. I Would like to know if I can join again the old swarm to retrieve my secret
2. I would like to know if I can flush/clean something about swarm cache that can help to retrieve definitive consistency
3. I would like t know If I can remove any swarm directory that can help to retrieve definitive consistency
4. I would like to know if some tools can help to manage obituaries, orphans,ghosts on Docker Swarm

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think for that question you might want to look at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com) (though I'm no expert at docker, so this might be on topic here). Also, SO works a bit different from forums, here one post should focus on one question (See [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) .

Comment: In fact the problem seems to be larger than swam, each time I try to up and run containers with their networks, they are some issues on network creation, a lot of inconsistent message about already exist, not found, and other messages when it's. internal, I did all I can do except reinstall docker, or remove such a /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db  like this, but I did all I can about network prune, it tied to install swarmctl but Docke seems to be too much recent regarding the swarctl client version ....